# How to create a new component with aurelia cli?

Tags: aurelia

Instead of creating new files manually, is there a command to create new components? Like `au new` but only for components:

**hello.html**

```
<template>

  <!-- Hello template -->

</template>
```

**hello.js**

```
export class Hello {

  constructor() {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typing `au generate` at the command line will give you the following list of options:

```
$ au generate
                      _ _          ____ _     ___
  __ _ _   _ _ __ ___| (_) __ _   / ___| |   |_ _|
 / _` | | | | '__/ _ \ | |/ _` | | |   | |    | |
| (_| | |_| | | |  __/ | | (_| | | |___| |___ | |
 \__,_|\__,_|_|  \___|_|_|\__,_|  \____|_____|___|

No Generator Specified. Available Generators:

attribute

    Creates a custom attribute class and places it in the project resources.

binding-behavior

    Creates a binding behavior class and places it in the project resources.

component

    Creates a custom component class and template (view model and view), placing them in the project source folder (or optionally in sub folders).

element

    Creates a custom element class and template, placing them in the project resources.

generator

    Creates a generator class and places it in the project generators folder.

task

    Creates a task and places it in the project tasks folder.

value-converter

    Creates a value converter class and places it in the project resources.
```

Simply type `au generate X` where X is one of the options listed. For example `au generate component`.

Comment: Mind naming your new component with kebab-case.